# How can I close an ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh

I have opened an ssh tunnel with `lucas-MacBook-Pro:~ donbeo$ ssh -D 8080 -f -C -q -N donbeo@149.157.140.64`

How can I close it now?

Answer (score 8):

Find the ssh tunnel's process id running on a specific port:

`ps aux | grep <port number>`

and kill the process:

`kill -9 <process id>`

Answer (score 2):

You can kill the `ssh` process like others with

```
kill -9 $PID
```

You can find `ssh` session process ID with

```
pgrep ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to type

```
~.
```

to exit/close the ssh connection.
I think

```
exit
```

also works.

Comment: can you post the full command? The connection is working in background

Comment: Ah sorry, background process... So you have to check for the pid and use 'kill -9 id'.